# There are no configured encoders for the "security" extension

Tags: symfony4, symfony-4.4

When I launch this command

```
php bin/console security:encode-password
```

I am getting this error

```
There are no configured encoders for the "security" extension.
```

Do anyone has an idea about this error, I am using Symfony 4
In bundles.php I  have security bundle activated

```
Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

Do anyone has an idea? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem. To fix it, try to add you an encoder to your security.yaml:

```
security:
   App\Entity\User:
        alogithm: auto
```